# Trouble creating even outward bevel on top edge of cylinder

Tags: modeling, bevel

Please bear with me, I am new to this software and 3D in general.

I currently have a shape consisting of a cylinder and a sphere embedded in the top of the cylinder:
[image: 3D model consisting of a cylinder and a sphere]

I am looking to create a curve that extends from the bottom half of the sphere and gently curves outward until reaching the cylinder's full width. I have drawn an example of what I want in MS Paint (it's a bit shaky but it's clear where it needs to be):[image: Drawing of the aforementioned desired shape provided as an example]

I have been playing around with the bevel tool, and while increasing the amount of segments does smooth out the curve, there is always a defined edge where the bevel stops:[image: Diagram showing how the bevelling of the edge suddenly stops]

I am looking to somehow get rid of this edge and create a smooth, even shape that slowly curves outward to the full width of the cylinder. I have been unable to find any solutions to this problem on both Google and this website.

I have seen similar posts where the solution was to apply the scale; I have already done that with both shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to BSE,

Here is what I would suggest:

(Optional):
In Object mode, select both your cylinder and your sphere (Shift+Left Click).
Use CTRL+J to join your meshes into a single object.
Although not required, you might find this makes your model easier to work on.

Select your cylinder and press Tab to enter Edit Mode

[image]

Use CTRL+R to add a loop-cut to the cylinder:

[image]

Rotate your view and select the top **face**:
Make sure you are in Face Select mode. The shortcut is 3 on the Number **row** of your keyboard (not the Number **pad**):

[image]

[image]

Use S to scale the face down. After press S you can also use the Numpad to enter a specific scale (i.e 0.5):

[image]

Now we want to bevel the edge loop in the center of the cylinder. First we need select it. The easiest way to do this is by using Alt-Select:

- Make sure you are in Edge Select mode. The shortcut is 2 on the Number **row** of your keyboard (not the Number **pad**):

[image]

- Hold Alt and Left-Click on one of the edges in the loop that we want to bevel:

[image]

You can now bevel as before, and hopefully get the result you are looking for.

[image]